# Chain rule with symbolic function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, derivative

My question refers to the Matlab symbolic toolbox.
I'm trying to derive a symbolic function that is a function of another symbolic function. Say that I have a function x that is an unspecified function x=x(y(theta)). I'd like to take the derivative of x with respect to theta: dx/dtheta=dx/dy * dy/dtheta

In Matlab I write

```
syms theta y(theta);
x=sym('x(y(theta))');
diff(x,theta)
```

The answer I get is 0. I really cannot figure out what is wrong with the code. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `function x=x(y(theta)).` this does not make sense. Is x the function or the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Derivating f(g(y)):

```
syms x,y
f = symfun(sym('f(x)'), [x])
g = symfun(sym('g(y)'), [y])
diff(f(g(y)),y)
```